# Como salvar os arquivos de gráficos (em png) gerados dentro de um loop

Tags: r, loop

Estou tentando gerar arquivos em png de gráficos que estão dentro de um loop.
Tentei fazer com a função **ggsave** mas não consigo inserir dentro do loop e fora do loop gera o arquivo vazio.

```
ggsave(paste0(dados [i], ".png"), path = "C:/Users/")

# Create data: 
set.seed(1)
dados <-as.data.frame(matrix (sample ( 0:100, 102 , replace=T) , ncol=17, byrow=TRUE))
colnames(dados) <- c ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17")

# To use the fmsb package, I have to add 2 lines to the dataframe: the max and min of each topic to show on the plot!
dados <- rbind(rep(100,17) , rep(0,17) , dados)

# Prepare title
mytitle <- c()

# Loop for each plot
for(i in 1:6){
  # Custom the radarChart !
  radarchart( dados[c(1,2,i+2),], axistype=1, 
              #custom polygon
              pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4  , 
              
              #custom the grid
              cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,50,100), cglwd=0.6,
              
              #custom labels
              vlcex=0.9,
              
              #title
              title=mytitle[i],         
  )
}
```

Comment: Olá, seria a R isso?

Comment: Olá, sim no R. Vou gerar 770 gráficos e gostaria que fossem salvos em arquivos, automatizando o processo. Obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

Adicione a linha png com o local onde você deseja salvar(você tem que ter permissão para escrita então mude como no exemplo abaixo para sua pasta de imagens)

Ao final da geração do seu gráfico adicione dev.off()

Código

```
...

for(i in 1:6){

  png(filename = paste0('C:\\Users\\SEU USUARIO\\Pictures\\',i,'.png'))

  radarchart( dados[c(1,2,i+2),], axistype=1, 
              #custom polygon
              pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4  , 
              
              #custom the grid
              cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,50,100), cglwd=0.6,
              
              #custom labels
              vlcex=0.9,
              
              #title
              title=mytitle[i],         
  )
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigada pela resposta!